# settings of columns are not saved in MySQL Workbench 6.3

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

iam working with a MySQL-server and use the MySQL Workbench 6.3 to configure and manage the server. I created some columns, which are working, but additionally I need another column for a timestamp of the system (in milliseconds). So I added another column "log" with the datatype `"TIMESTAMP(6)"` and chose as Default/Expression `"CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"`. Then I clicked on apply and the system said:"Apply changes to ...". Hence the changed should be applied, but the configuration of the datatype TIMESTAMP(6) and the Default/Expression is not saved.

So the saved datatype is just "TIMESTAMP" and the Default/Expression is "NULL". Anyone knows why these settings are not saved?

Comment: What is the version of your mysql?

Comment: In that case I would try to insert a record, then update it and then check if the expected data is retrieved from the table. It may be that workbench displays the type settings incorrectly.

Comment: Well, I want that the server inserts the logtime itself. for example:
value | logtime
-------------------
10     | 12:43:11.123435

Comment: Can you give us the SQL-Command which is executed? Have tried it to execute that SQL manually?

Comment: @xy36 do not tell me what you would like to do. Do it and check what is stored in the database.

Comment: @shadow the value stores the correct value, the logtime is null

Comment: @etalon11 iam using the mysql workbench and didnt use sql-commands manually. Sorry iam just a beginner;)

Comment: Before you apply the command, you can see the sql. Can you post this?

Comment: ALTER TABLE `opc`.`opc_data` 
CHANGE COLUMN `log` `log` TIMESTAMP(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL ;

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who has the same problem, I found a solution. It didnt apply the values, because the datatype and expression were different...

I needed to add the 6 to the expression as well, like:

TIMESTAMP(6) | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)

Now it is working for me!

Comment: saved me some time there mate :)